# IF statement with multiple criteria and multiple possible results

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet and I need a formula to give me one of three possible results (good, neutral, bad) based on data from two cells. MTD and YTD on budget would be good, MTD on budget & YTD below (AND vice versa) would be neutral, and MTD & YTD below budget would be bad.

My budget is 83%. On my sheet MTD is D1 and YTD is F1. I'm using the smile characters as good, neutral, and bad (CHAR 74,75,76).

Comment: OK, you indicate that you know about the `IF` function (and it is a *function*, not a *statement*, BTW / FYI).  Do you know about the `AND` and `OR` functions?  Research them.  Have you tried anything?  We prefer question-askers to try to solve the problem themselves, first, ***and then to tell us what they have tried*** as part of the question.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Further, your question is hard to understand — what individual tests do you want to do?  `D1 < 83` and `F1 < 83`? Or should it be `0.83`?  Or `0.83` times something?  Or should the tests be `<=`, `>`, or `>=`?

Comment: Regarding your follow-up question: it's called "conditional formatting"; look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I made a quick attempt and this and came up with a rough version that works. It probably isn't the best so hopefully someone responds with a more elegant solution, but try this:

=IF(AND($B$2<=$B$1,$B$3<=$B$1),"Good",IF(AND($B$3>$B$1,$B$2>$B$1),"Bad", "Neutral"))

B1 = 0.83 (just my value for budget)
B2 = YTD value entered by user
B3 = MTD value entered by user

Please note, this doesn't really have any user error catching code (values other than numbers, etc...

Hope this helps at least a little bit,

Comment: That worked really well! Thank you. Would you know how to change the type color based on a result? For example if my result for the formula you gave me has a :) then make it green, :( would be red and :| would be yellow?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a tricky way (that might be considered elegant). 
I’ll assume that `< 83` is the “good” condition.  Use this formula:

```
=CHOOSE((D1<83)+(F1<83)+1, "bad", "neutral", "good")
```

Logical expressions like `D1<83` evaluate to one of the Boolean values
`TRUE` and `FALSE`, which are numerically equal to 1 and 0, respectively. 
By adding `(D1<83)+(F1<83)`, we get the number of criteria
that are in the good state:
0 (neither), 1 (exactly one; i.e., one ***or*** the other), or 2 (both). 
Add 1 to get a number that is 1, 2, or 3.  Then use

```
=CHOOSE(n, value1, value2, value3, …)
```

to get the *`value`* corresponding to the computed number *`n`*.

Here are some test results:

```
D     F     formula result
17    42    good
17    99    neutral
99    42    neutral
99    99    bad
```

Comment: This answer definitely edges mine out, thanks for posting...I forgot about the Choose function.