# Assigning Numbers based on a text value

Tags: windows

I need help assigning numbers to a particular cell. In my spreadsheet, I have 3 columns (C, D & E) that say "TRUE" or "FALSE" based on information from other cells. Now I need to assign a value of 1 if either D1 or E1 say "TRUE" and I need to assign a value of 1.5 in column C if they both say "TRUE"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you using Microsoft Excel? Also, sharing what you've tried already will help you get better answers. You may [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/966398/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: I believe that this is a duplicate (albeit with different values required): http://superuser.com/questions/135739/how-do-i-assign-a-number-value-to-a-non-numerical-value-in-excel  It might be worth checking the response there initially as you may be able to tailor it to this question as well

Comment: Have you tried a simple IF statement?

Comment: This seems very similar to [IF statement with multiple criteria and multiple possible results](http://superuser.com/q/960796/150988).

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Excel, here's what you would put in the C column.

```
=IF(AND($D1=TRUE,$E1=TRUE),1.5,IF(OR($D1=TRUE,$E1=TRUE),1,0))
```

This has been built in a way that you can use the drag feature, so if you put this in C1, then drag from the bottom-right corner of the cell to C2, it will be rewritten by Excel to address D2 and E2.